# Can I run reCAPTCHA on my localhost Apache server in this Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, captcha, recaptcha

I am pretty new in **PHP** and **Laravel** and I have the following problem: into my Laravel application I have to implement a page containing a form that have to contain a **Google reCAPTCHA** field. The submitted form will be validated if the **reCAPTCHA** field is correctly compiled. I have no previous experience with **reCAPTCHA**.

I have found this tutorial:

https://tuts.codingo.me/google-recaptcha-in-laravel-application

In this tutorial it says that:

> I will first visit Google reCaptcha site
>   https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ and **register new site there**. Good
>   thing is that you can insert multiple **domains**, so same captcha
>   placement can work on your development domain and production domain.

So it says that I have to register my domain here:

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list

Why? Because in this way the **reCAPTCHA** service can send the captcha text to my website? Or what?

My problem is that at this time my **Laravel** web site is running on my local development laptop (on my XAMPP localhost Apache server).

Can I test it on my localhost server in some way or is it impossible to do and I have to deploy it on my remote server using the associated domain?

Answer (score 1):

Your reCAPTCHA will work on domains you provide and their subdomains. If you need localhost, just add it to the list

For more info, [read the docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#im-getting-an-error-localhost-is-not-in-the-list-of-supported-domains.-what-should-i-do).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You have to add in domains list:
**localhost**
or
**127.0.0.1**